# Switching Djanto's STATIC_URL to HTTPS when site is accessed via HTTPS

Tags: python, django, http, https, static-site

I have a Django project set up in the following way:

- Apache serving Django via WSGI on `https://example.com` and `https://example.com`.
- Apache also serving `http://static.example.com` and `https://static.example.com`.

The templates are set up as such in regards to static files (for example):

```
{% load staticfiles %}
[...]
<script src="{% static 'site/js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

There is however a problem. When the Django site is accessed via HTTPS, browsers tend to complain about security as the static files are STILL served via HTTP. For instance Chrome:

[image: Chrome doesn't like it]

So the question is, **is there a way to tell Django to use `https://static.example.com/` as a `STATIC_URL` when the site is accessed via HTTPS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a separate subdomain for your assets, you can use a [protocol-relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) which always serves on the same protocol as the source page:

```
STATIC_URL = "//static.example.com"
```